# Navigating Hyperlink in SharePoint List in Teams

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I have a SharePoint List and one of the columns is a multi-line text item usually containing a hyperlink to a Word or PDF document in a SharePoint Document Library on the same site. When I use this List in SharePoint in a browser and click on one of the hyperlinks, it all works as expected in that I can click the link to open the document to view and then if I want to go back to the List, I use the Back button in the browser. Unfortunately, in the TEAMS desktop app, the Back button is missing.
Does anyone have any idea how I can go Back from the document view when using this List in the TEAMS app?

Comment: If i understand your issue correct, you mean to say if you are opening a document clicking on hyperlink in SharePoint https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKLro.png you are able to open the document and there is a back button to navigate back https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjiJ7.png but on adding that SP list as tab in MS Teams if you are trying the same, the document opens but there is no back button to navigate back. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOmbP.png Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Your last image showing TEAMS is the same as mine, i.e. no way back. As far as I can tell, there is no keyboard shortcut either or at least I haven't found one yet!

Comment: This seems like by design behaviour only. One option would be to refresh the tab in order to go back. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdPYm.png

Comment: Well, if it's by design, I don't personally feel that it's good design. My list is quite long and if I'm working low down the list and have to Reload the tab, it scrolls right back to the beginning again. Even an "Open in Browser" option in the right-click Context menu would be some help. As it is, it's a poor experience.

Comment: I understand, its not good user experience. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: OK, I've done that now. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

On another forum, somebody pointed me to the history feature in TEAMS which does the trick very nicely. You just need to hover over the back button to see the options rather than click it directly.
[History Feature in TEAMS](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/21/introducing-history-menu-in-microsoft-teams-desktop/)